# wsHttpBinding over Internet

Tags: .net, wcf, wshttpbinding

We have a set of WCF services hosted in IIS and secured with wsHttpBinding and exposed on Internet. When I am trying to consume those services from a client I am getting an error
"Request for the security token has invalid or malformed elements."

I am using

```
    <security mode="Message">
          <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
     </security>
```

Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the security mode to none.

Alternativily, over the internet basichttpbinding over ssl with basic authenication works well.